# Not getting correct result when solving a challenge

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this coding challenge
Result that I need

```
 1 8 9 16 17
 2 7 10 15 18
 3 6 11 14 19
 4 5 12 13 20
```

logic for colindex that is even
rowsNumber * colIndex+1 // 4*0+1 which gives 1 for column 0 row 1

logic for colindex  that is odd
rowsNumber*(colIndex+1); // 4*(1+1) which gives 8 for column 2 row 1

```js
const rowsNumber = 4;
const columnsNumber = 5;

for(let i = 0; i<rowsNumber; i++) {

    for(let j = 0; j<columnsNumber; j++) {
        if(j % 2 == 0) {
        console.log(rowsNumber * j + 1);
    }   else {
        console.log(rowsNumber * (j + 1))
    }
  }

}
```

I am getting following result

```
1
8
9
16
17
1
8
9
16
17
1
8
9
16
17
1
8
9
16
17
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is only valid for first row. You'll also have to consider the rowIndex.
The actual logic is
For even rows : rowsNumber * (colIndex+1) - rowIndex
For odd rows :  rowsNumber * colIndex+1 + rowIndex
So the code would be as follows

```
const rowsNumber = 4;
const columnsNumber = 5;
for(let i=0;i<rowsNumber;i++) {
    for(let j=0;j<columnsNumber;j++) {
        if(j%2 == 0) {
        console.log(rowsNumber*j+1+i);
    }   else {
        console.log(rowsNumber*(j+1)-i)
    }
  }
}
```

This gives the output as :

```
1
8
9
16
17
2
7
10
15
18
3
6
11
14
19
4
5
12
13
20
```